# Find a sequence of continuous periodic functions which converge in $L^2$ to a discontinuous periodic function

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Find a sequence of continuous periodic functions which converge in $L^2$ to a discontinuous periodic function. (**Hint**- Try converging to the **square wave** function)

**Answer:**

If $\{f_n(x) \}_n$ be the sequence of continuous periodic function converging to a discontinuous periodic function $f(x)$ in $L^2$, then $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2dx =0.$$

We have to show the above.

The hints says, try converging to the square wave function.

An example of square wave function is

$f(x)=\text{sgn} \left( \sin \frac{2 \pi}{T}\right)$, where $\text{sgn}$ denote the $\text{sign}$ funnction , i.e, $\pm 1$ and $T$ is the period.

**Now how to use this ?**

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I think all you need is the Fourier series of $f$. If $f$ is periodic in $[0,2\pi]$, then its Fourier series converges in $L^2([0,2\pi])$ if and only if $f$ is in $L^2([0,2\pi])$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Norm_convergence